# Vimeo login and redirect

Tags: redirect, vimeo

I am building my own website with embeded vimeo videos, her is my test env: luddiogkarlo.com/tp

I am a Vimeo Pro member

I am using vimeo ondemand to host the videos.

I need to make sure that the user is logged on vimeo when they visit my page, or by clicking at button and then redirect to luddiogkarlo.com/tp.
I have tried created an app and used "https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize" but the user get's everytime prompt to "Allow this application to:" this is not what I wan’t.

The only thing i wan't is when user subscribes they get redirected to my webside.
Moreover, when user logs on to vimeo, they will be redirected to my website

is this possible?

Comment: `I need to make sure that the user is logged on vimeo when they visit my page` why? (Not an expert on this, but the "allow this application to" dialogue may be unavoidable....)

Comment: to avoid the user to visit vimeo first and login, and then return to my website manualy.

Comment: But why do you need the user to be logged on to Vimeo in the first place?

Comment: I am using vimeo ondemand to host my videos and to view them you need to be logged on to vimeo.